# Can I use \input{file.tex} or similar to efficiently bring content (not a whole document) from a LaTeX file into a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: include, jupyter-notebook, latex

I am new to Jupyter notebooks and Python and have started using these to make materials for a workshop so that I can also produce a handout. I have useful content in various LaTeX files that I would like to include in a notebook.

I would like to know whether there is a command that will allow me to efficiently bring my already modularized content into a notebook. I will be happy to take suggestions on any approach to my problem in case the LaTeX route is the wrong way to proceed.

As a particular case, suppose an external file fig.tex has only a stand-alone tikzpicture (that I have successfully included in another LaTeX document).  If I start a notebook code cell with 
`%%itikz` and follow with `\input{fig}` I obtain error messages.

I can remedy the problem if I add a preamble with `\documentclass{}`, many necessary `\usepackage{}` and `\usetikzlibrary{}` commands (which I have already included at the top of the notebook), and wrap the content with  begin/end document commands.

There is more manual handling here than I would like. Is there a more efficient way to include the tikzfigure content?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out with itikz you have an `--implicit-pic` option that fills in the preamble for you.

In principle, with this option, your cell would look like the following:

```
%%itikz --implicit-pic

% my awesome figure
\input{path/to/fig}
```

This creates a tex file populated like so:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]

% my awesome figure
\input{path/to/fig}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In addition when using an `implicit-pic` it is usefull to load tikz packages and set options . To quote from the [Quickstart](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jbn/itikz/blob/master/Quickstart.ipynb) guide:

> In an `--implicit-pic`, it's often useful to:
>
> - Set the `\tikzpicture[scale=X]` via `--scale=<X>` while iterating.
> - Set the `\usepackage{X,Y,Z}` via `--tex-packages=<X,Y,Z>`
> - Set the `\usetizlibrary{X,Y,Z}` via `--tiz-libraries=<X,Y,Z>`

For more info, see items 16-20 in the Quickstart notebook.